# How to allocate a row value into to different values based on percentage in a selection from table

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the vague question in advance.

I have the following table:

```
State   Sales
AL  1000
AK  2000
MI  4000
MA  3000
PA  1500
WY  3000
NY  2000
VM  1000
```

Now each state belongs to a region or multiple regions:

```
Regions 
AB: AL, 50%AK
CD: 50%Ak, MI
EF: MA, PA, 25%WY
GH: 75%WY, NY, VM
```

I want the following table:

```
State Region Sales
AL   AB   1000
AK   AB   1000
AK   CD   1000
MI   CD   4000
MA   EF   3000
PA   EF   1500
WY   EF   750
WY   GH   2250
NY   GH   2000
VM   GH   1000
```

I have some experience with SQL but i am not sure how to proceed. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my previous answer, your schema is correct, but you should be adding the data on regions table(or rename it to another table name, it is so confusing when this table is named Regions) something like this:

```
region_code state_code  percentage
AB           AL           100
AB           AK           50
CD           Ak           50
CD           MI           100
EF           MA           100
EF           PA           100
EF           WY           25
GH           WY           75
GH           NY           100
GH           VM           100
```

Then your query would be something like:

```
SELECT State.code, Region.code, ((Region.percentage * State.sales) / 100) as Sales 
FROM State
INNER JOIN Region
ON State.code = Region.state_code
```

> NOTE: this answer is made to have a small changes on your schema. This answer serve as an example or to give you an idea. I suggest you analyze more on how your database schema should be made. Normalizing database and Proper naming of tables should be done if needed

Comment: how do you split the sales on the percentage basis?

Comment: ahh i see, that is the function of those percentages. hmmmm